# How do I use word breaking in ReportLab?

Tags: pdf-generation, mediawiki, reportlab, wordbreaker

I use MWLIB and ReportLab to convert MediaWiki articles to PDF.

I got this really long link that for whatever reason causes the sentence above to have really long spaces between the words. I think the link makes such a long word that it just draws out the sentence above.

See the picture here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/543/tzfo.png/

Is there anyway to force word breaking on words longer than a certain set of characters in ReportLab? I think that would fix it.

PS; Here's some code:

The method def breakLinesCJK() in reportlab/paragraph.py. It uses the method wordSplit() from reportlab.lib.textsplit.py

```
def breakLinesCJK(self, width):
    """Initially, the dumbest possible wrapping algorithm.
    Cannot handle font variations."""

    if not isinstance(width,(list,tuple)): maxWidths = [width]
    else: maxWidths = width
    style = self.style
    self.height = 0

    #for bullets, work out width and ensure we wrap the right amount onto line one
    _handleBulletWidth(self.bulletText, style, maxWidths)
    frags = self.frags
    nFrags = len(frags)
    if nFrags==1 and not hasattr(frags[0],'cbDefn'):
        f = frags[0]
        if hasattr(self,'blPara') and getattr(self,'_splitpara',1):
            return f.clone(kind=0, lines=self.blPara.lines)
        #single frag case
        lines = []
        lineno = 0
        if hasattr(f,'text'):
            text = f.text
        else:
            text = ''.join(getattr(f,'words',[]))

        print "USE WORDSPLIT ELSE TREPORTLAB EXT = '',JOIN"

        from reportlab.lib.textsplit import wordSplit
        lines = wordSplit(text, maxWidths[20], f.fontName, f.fontSize)
        #the paragraph drawing routine assumes multiple frags per line, so we need an
        #extra list like this
        #  [space, [text]]
        #
        wrappedLines = [(sp, [line]) for (sp, line) in lines]
        return f.clone(kind=0, lines=wrappedLines, ascent=f.fontSize, descent=-0.2*f.fontSize)
    elif nFrags<=0:
        return ParaLines(kind=0, fontSize=style.fontSize, fontName=style.fontName,
                        textColor=style.textColor, lines=[],ascent=style.fontSize,descent=-0.2*style.fontSize)

    #general case nFrags>1 or special
    if hasattr(self,'blPara') and getattr(self,'_splitpara',0):
        return self.blPara
    autoLeading = getattr(self,'autoLeading',getattr(style,'autoLeading',''))
    calcBounds = autoLeading not in ('','off')
    return cjkFragSplit(frags, maxWidths, calcBounds)
```

The code in textplit.py is also significant but it's just too much too copy, but just like paragraph, anyone with reportlab should have this file.

Comment: There are ways, both built in and custom-built, to handle word wrapping in ReportLab, but without any code of what you're doing it's hard to recommend how to proceed.

Comment: I use the script files that comes with ReportLab and MWLIB. I would have to show you all of them for it to be any help, unless you could tell me a specific script file you'd want to see.

I just wanted to know if there's any built-in variable you can change to make the word-breaking more aggressive.

Comment: Or more specifically, I just want to know whether there is any way of forcing words longer than a certain amount of characters to break so I can fix the problem in the picture.

Anyway, I updated my main post with some code from scripts I think are significant.